# How to make visual studio stop using IIS Local

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7, iis-express

So i've been using visual studio 2017 to develop a .net MVC application, when I click to run and debug the app locally, it used to run under 'http://localhost:80.ApplicationName' using IIS Express. Recently I had to change my application properties to run under local IIS, so now the url reads 'https://localhost.ApplicationName'.

After using the local IIS I wanted to switch it back to using IIS Express, but even when I change the application properties back to IIS express, it still runs under some local host, I can see in my task bar that IIS Express is running with 2 sites but visual studio always loads the IIS Local address.

The reason this is a problem is because, I want to be able to run my app and change javascript whilst debugging, having an IIS Local copy running means that I have to re-build when I want a change to the code to be recognised, in IIS Express I can do it on the fly and just refresh my cache.

Can anyone help me get my visual studio application running under IIS Express as if I had never touched it? I just want the default, almost like a reset.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your debug properties for your project?

Answer (score 0):

remove .vs/config folder and rebuild i think

Comment: I did this but now I have to restart the project every time I want to debug javascript, instead of just CTRL + F5